# g++ function attribute fastcall params(3) . How to set as default

Tags: c++, g++

I am looking for an option in g++ to set the default attributes of functions to fastcall or regparm (number) but I am unable to find it.

Comment: You could make a GCC plugin or an extension in [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) doing that (adding default attributes) for you.

Comment: Can you be more specific? And show us more of the research you've performed.

Comment: In various compilers it is possible to define the way a function receives it's arguments. In the microsoft compiler i have found from the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46t77ak2.aspx that it is possible for example to define the default attributes in order to use as default the convention "fastcall" using the /Gr compiler directive, but I haven't found asimilar for g++.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch In the microsoft compiler as I have seen ( I don't use it ) it is possible, in g++ there is not a simple way ?

Comment: If there was such an option or pragma, that would also solve my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385849/conflicting-type-attributes-specified-for-virtual-destructor . Apparently, there is none, but someone with more exhaustive knowledge should confirm that.