# Conflicting type attributes specified for virtual destructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, g++, virtual-functions, calling-convention

The following extract was previously compiling under Borland C++, MSVC and OpenWatcom:

```
class aaa {
    virtual _fastcall ~aaa();
};

class bbb:public aaa {
};
```

It doesn't compile under gcc/g++ (MinGW 4.8.0). Error:

```
probz.cpp:7:7: error: conflicting type attributes specified for 'virtual bbb::~bbb()'
 class bbb:public aaa {
       ^
probz.cpp:3:20: error:   overriding 'virtual aaa::~aaa()'
   virtual _fastcall ~aaa()=0;///can't be abstract
                     ^
```

Obviously, there is no bbb::~bbb()!

### EDIT

The actual class hierarchy is bigger, there are many classes **bbb** inheriting from **aaa**, and there are intermediate members in between, i.e. bbb extends abb, which extends aab, which extends aaa. **aaa** indeed has an abstract virtual destructor, which gets implementation in the intermediate classes, but not in the leaves. Yes, I can remove the `__fastcall` attribute and it compiles. Is it a gcc limitation that I cannot adjust the calling convention?

Comment: You can have a pure virtual destructor, but you still need to provide a definition, otherwise how would any derived class destroy its base class? Add `inline aaa::~aaa() {}` below the definition of `class aaa`.

Comment: Why do you think there is no `bbb::~bbb()`? Though when lining a definition for the pure-virtual base-dtor should be found.

Comment: Abstractness is neither the cause nor the point of the question. Change the destructor into <code>virtual _fastcall ~aaa() {/*I am not abstract*/};</code>, and you still have the same error. This is taken from a working and useful library which I am trying to port.

Comment: @MKaama Then try removing `_fastcall`, it's possible gcc (MinGW) doesn't know what that means. I'll reopen the question, but please get rid of the pure virtual destructor or add a definition for it.

Comment: @Praetorian THX for pointing out, I've fixed that answer.

Comment: It seems gcc accepted the `__fastcall` attribute for the base class destructor, and is complaining about not having it specified on the derived class.  That makes sense - you need a consistent calling convention for all the implementations of the same virtual function, or you can't dispatch to them polymorphically.  Perhaps those other compilers were prepared to let it be implied, but GCC isn't - such specifiers are outside the C++ language standard so compilers are free to adopt whatever they think sensible.

Comment: @TonyD It sounds logical, but to specify __fastcall in the derived class I would have to override the destructor, which I don't want to do.

Comment: @MKaama then Praetorian's suggestion of removing it from the base class sounds like a reasonable alternative... less non-Standard crap in your code the better IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`__fastcall`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xa169sk.aspx) is a calling convention.

It's a non standard feature : the double underscore at the begin of the name means that it's **implementation specific**. Calling conventions are tightly related to the systems and CPU architectures. This one seems to be relevant for x86 32 bit mode.

Some recommendations:

- You shouldn't bother with calling conventions unless absolutely required (e.g.when interfacing with precompiled libraries or [extern dlls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx)).
- The level of optimizing that modern compilers perform does no longuer require such manual tuning. The same applies with keyword `register`
- If your code really needs it on some platforms, you should foresee a `#define` in one of your header and make sure with conditional compilation that it's defined to nothing on platform/compilers where it's not relevant (for DLLs this approach is usual, with a library specific `#define`).
- Calling conventions should be the same in all the derived classes, so it's better declared in the base class.  For **virtual  functions** this is an implicitely **mandatory requirement** !  Imagine that your base class passes parameters via the stack, and the derived class via the registers (fastcall).  Now what code should your compiler generate if you make a polymorphic call via a base class pointer ? And what would happen if two derived classes would use different calling conventions ?
- You can't assume that a calling convention is automatically inherited :  the standard makes no guarantee, here
- If you have to specify a calling convetion, **prefer an external linkage specifier** if possible (e.g. `extern "C"` ) because this is the only calling convention relevant semantic that is supported by the standard.

Additional information:

- [`__cdecl`, `__stdcall`, and other usual calling conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/984x0h58.aspx)
- [Calling convetions demistified](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1388/Calling-Conventions-Demystified)